# Kendo templates and reserved words

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

From the [GridInForm C# project available from Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/submit-form-containing-grid-along-with-other-input-elements) the file Index.cshtml contains this grid (among other things):

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Products)
    .Name("Products")
    .ToolBar(tools => tools.Create().Text("Add new product"))
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell).CreateAt(GridInsertRowPosition.Bottom))
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.Name).ClientTemplate("#= Name #" + 
            "<input type='hidden' name='Products[#= index(data)#].Name' value='#= Name #' />");

        columns.Bound(p => p.ProductID).Hidden().ClientTemplate("#= ProductID #" +
            "<input type='hidden' name='Products[#= index(data)#].ProductID' value='#= ProductID #' />");

        columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Width(100);
    })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Model(model => 
        {
            model.Id(p => p.ProductID);
            model.Field(p => p.ProductID).Editable(false);
        })
        .ServerOperation(false)
    )
)
```

And this javascript function:

```
function index(dataItem) {
    var data = $("#Products").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data();
    return data.indexOf(dataItem);
}
```

My question is about finding more information about the `data` parameter being passed in the template to the `index` function (in the call to `ClientTemplate`). What is it and where does it come from?

Comment: I bet the dataItem references a row in the grid that points to a record in the dataSource bound to the grid. The data variable above in the index() function contains all of your model fields from that row or index in the dataSource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line shows the use of the `index()` function:

```
"<input type='hidden' name='Products[#= index(data)#].ProductID' value='#= ProductID #' />"
```

`data` in this line is a built in object that the Kendo framework creates when it parses the client template. It represents the data object for that particular row.

You can read a bit about the `data` object here: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq#how-do-i-use-a-javascript-function-in-a-column-client-template? under the question titled "How do I use a JavaScript function in a column client template?"

If you want to know specifically what it looks like, you can add a `console.wirte(JSON.stringify(dataItem))` to the `index()` function to see it's exact structure.

**edit**

Additionally, the client template is just a text string that the Kendo Javascript parses as each column in each row is being created. At that time, it has the data object for that row which it uses to insert the values into the grid. The MVC is just a wrapper for the Javascript libraries that actually generate the HTML in the document.

Comment: Do you happen to have a link to the docs on the 'built in object' part? That's what I was guessing but I cannot seem to find anything about it from Telerik.

Comment: I was looking for this exact thing the other day, and found it somewhere... I'll see if I can figure out where it was.

Comment: Even that documentation is pretty sparse on the details. But at least it confirms that it is indeed apart of the API.

Comment: The telerik docs are abyssimal. They make msdn look like the rosetta stone.

Comment: I spent the last 6 months working on a website project where we used used the Kendo grid (and others) extensively. At this point I've finally learned my way around their documentation style, and can usually find what I'm after. But there was a definite learning curve. 6 or 7 years ago MSDN was pretty wild too, but they've made great improvements in recent years.

Comment: Compared to the older Telerik controls for MVC documentation the kendo docs have a long road to go.